# Lifecycle of Android manufacturer bundled application

Tags: android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

We are looking at options with an Android phone manufacturer to bundle one of our applications. For an app that makes use of sqlite as the data store, how does one manage the lifecycle i.e upgrade, downgrade, connection with play store? If anyone has any relevant experience please do share.

Notes

1 - `onDowngrade` is available API level 11 onwards while we have a minimum restriction of API 7/8

2 - The remove all updates on packaged applications does a blind uninstall of new updates

Comment: How is that different from an ordinary application? SQLiteOpenHelper has all the methods

Comment: Supposedly since one cannot uninstall manufacturer bundled apps without rooting, there is a special setting to remove new updates that does not follow the normal SQLiteOpenHelper upgrade/downgrade paradigm. Thats what I heard, need a confirmation on that.